# Multiple Click Events - Clutter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Alright, I've got a tool I'm building that calls functions that set JQuery event handlers, but the result is that the same handlers will be set over and over again as different functions are called.  It is working as expected: The action of the most recent handler called is the one that executes.  Is this causing clutter, though?  In other words, when I put a click event on something and then another one, does the first one still exist?  If so, how do I remove it?

Thanks!

Here's what I mean, for clarity:

```
$('#ele').click(function() {
    Do Something
}
$('#ele').click(function() {
    Do Something Else
}
```

Comment: It's hard to give you any advice on code we can't see.

Comment: I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `click` will **Add a new Click Handler**

This will print to console "first second"

```
$("#test").click(function() { console.log("first"); });
$("#test").click(function() { console.log("second"); });
```

You can use `unbind` to remove the previous click handler. This will only print "second" to console

```
$("#test").click(function() { console.log("first"); });
$("#test").unbind("click").click(function() { console.log("second"); });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjLW3/)

Comment: That's what I was hoping for!  Thanks.

Comment: @JS Please recheck my answer as I checked my assumptions and `click` will continue to add new event handlers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(selector).toggle()`, like this:

```
(function ($){
    $("#ele").toggle(a, b);
})(jQuery);
```

And here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Diltage/tapsy/2/), hope this can help you :p